# y/n input validation including no input Enter key

Tags: java, validation, if-statement, input, while-loop

I am trying to catch no input (enter key) and invalid input everything but y/n in one method. I tried it two different ways (pasted) but I cannot make work both “enter key” and “mistype y/n” together. Thank you for your help.

1st attempt:

```
public static String askToContinue(Scanner sc) {

String choice = "";
boolean isValid = false;

while (!isValid){System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
    if (sc.hasNext()){
        choice = sc.next();
        isValid = true;
    } else {System.out.println("Error! "
                + "This entry is required. Try again");    
    }

    if (isValid && !choice.equals("y") || !choice.equals("n")) {
        System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'y' or 'n'. Try again");
        isValid = false;
    }
   }
    //sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
    System.out.println();
    return choice;
   }        



   2nd attempt

    public static String askToContinue(Scanner sc) {
    System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
    String choice;



    while (true) {choice = sc.next();

    //?????????????????????????????????????????????????????
        if (choice.length() == 0){ System.out.println("Error! "
                + "This entry is required. Try again");
            continue;
        }


        if (!(choice.equals("y") || choice.equals("n"))) {
            System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'y' or 'n'. Try                   again");
            continue;
        }

        break;    
    }

    sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
    System.out.println();
    return choice;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with 1st attempt of your code. I explained with comment line which is included in below code like ;

```
public static String askToContinue(Scanner sc) {
    String choice = "";
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (!isValid) {
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.nextLine(); //to reads all line , because this cannot read with empty enter input
        isValid = true;
        if (choice.isEmpty()) {  //this isEmpty for empty enter
            System.out.println("Error! "
                    + "This entry is required. Try again");
        }
        System.out.println(choice);
        //this logic if not y or n , it will return error
        if (!choice.equals("y") && !choice.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'y' or 'n'. Try again");
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    //sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
    System.out.println();
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, "isEmpty" and ! && ! comments really helped.

Comment: No problem mate, if helped , can you approve this as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement in first case is wrong. You are checking if choice `is not equal to 'y'` **or** `not equal to 'n'` which will always be true .

Change

```
if (isValid && !choice.equals("y") || !choice.equals("n"))
```

To

```
if (isValid && !choice.equals("y") && !choice.equals("n"))
```